# If $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^m$ prove $x^*y = \|x\|_2\|y\|_2 \cos \alpha$

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

If $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^m$ prove

$$x^*y = \|x\|_2\|y\|_2 \cos \alpha$$

where $x^*y$ denotes the inner product of two vectors, and alpha is the angle between $x$ and $y$.

---

*Attempt*

\begin{align}
LHS = \left(x^*y\right)^2 &= \left(\bar x_1y_1 + \bar x_2y_2 + \cdots + \bar x_my_m \right)^2 \\ 
    &= (\bar x_1y_1)^2 + \cdots + (\bar x_my_m)^2+ 2\sum_{j = 1}^m\sum_{i \neq j}^m \bar x_iy_i\bar x_j y_j \dots
\end{align}

---

For more clarity: (2.3)

[image]

Comment: What is the *? Is that multiplication? Typically, multiplication in $m$-dimensional complex space uses the dot product, right? Or am I missing something? And what is $\alpha$? The angle between $x$ and $y$? And why are you using the 2-adic norm?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Edited. The star is conjugate transpose, and $\alpha$ is the only thing it could be given the context.

Comment: The LHS can be complex in this expression, so the equation makes no sense.

Comment: @Paul Maybe I should say *inner product*. That's what my book says. *Numerical Linear Algebra* by Trefethen and Bau.

Comment: I understand that it’s an inner product.  The problem is that the RHS of the equation is real, while the LHS is not.

Comment: Maybe we should take it as only being defined when $x^*y$ is real.

Comment: I still don't understand where the 2-adic norm comes in. $

Comment: @InterstellarProbe I think the problem is that I don't understand the problem well, and tried to simplify it.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe I've posted the passage from the book.

Comment: In your original problem statement (no simplification), you have on the RHS: $\|x\|_2$. Ignoring everything else in your problem, this does not make sense, as this is the notation for the 2-adic norm. The problem is that this norm has no canonical construction over complex numbers. It can be proven to exist, but not much more than that.  So, I am questioning your notation, which I'm guessing does not mean the 2-adic norm. What is it supposed to mean?

Comment: That notation could also mean the $l_2$ Norm of the vector so I wouldn't immediately assume their notation is bad just not the notation you were expecting.

Comment: I'd try showing the cosine equation first when the vectors are real and $m=2$. The inner product you mentioned is a complex number when the vectors are complex unless it's with the vector and itself (or some other unusual case). So I believe the comment the author makes at the bottom is that the cosine equation still holds for a complex cosine function. I'm not personally familiar with that statement but it's plausible :-)

Comment: @N8tron I see. I had not seen that notation before. Fair enough.